# Web page scalable to all resolutions ..?

Tags: css, web

I have recently uploaded my web pages to a server and have been testing it in different screen sizes and resolutions. My web pages look good until I download to smaller resolutions such as 800 x 600, 640 x 480 and 240 x 320. Can anyone tell me what code I should be using to make my web page scalable to all resolutions?

This is mywebsite [bingotuzla](http://www.bingotuzla.ba)

Comment: This looks bad on anything < 1600px.

Comment: Take a look to Bootstrap

Comment: you can use width and height in percentages.. also check the below answers.

Comment: Can I use a java script for the solution of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Use [css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) so that you can fit best to all resolutions. Also it's good tool in FF `ctrl+l.shift+m` to check smaller resolutions

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your website Design to **[Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)**

Responsive Web Design (RWD) is a Web design approach aimed at crafting sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from mobile phones to desktop computer monitors)